# Which Eclipse Photon plugin provides a "JPA Tools" context menu entry?

Tags: eclipse, jpa, eclipse-plugin, dali, eclipse-photon

I do not see a <kbd>JPA Tools</kbd> item in a context menu of my project in Eclipse *Photon.*

In my Eclipse *Oxygen* installation I have this item. It is [provided](http://git.eclipse.org/c/dali/webtools.dali.git/tree/jpa/plugins/org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui/property_files/jpt_jpa_ui.properties) by the "Eclipse Web Tools Platform" provider's "Dali Java Persistence Tools - JPA UI" plugin. I can verify that it is installed in my Eclipse *Oxygen* by going to <kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>About Eclipse SDK</kbd> → <kbd>Installation Details</kbd> → <kbd>Plug-ins</kbd> and searching for `org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui`.

The only JPA plugin that is not yet installed in my Eclipse *Photon* from the "Photon" repo is "Dali Java Persistence Tools - JPA Diagram Editor". But I do not have it in my Eclipse *Oxygen* installation as well.

Which plugin should I install in order to enable the <kbd>JPA Tools</kbd> entry?

Comment: You may need to add the JPA Facet to your project.

Comment: @BrianVosburgh, that is good hint. I realized that I do not have a "JPA" entry in a "Project Facets" tab.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the plugin name, but [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140200/which-eclipse-photon-plugin-provides-a-jpa-tools-context-menu-entry#comment89276387_51140200) worked for me:

1. Open the context menu of the project
2. Choose <kbd>Properties</kbd>
3. In the <kbd>Project Facets</kbd> section check the <kbd>JPA</kbd> checkbox